# Sectioning command that automatically creates label

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm trying to define a custom section command that will also define a corresponding label after a bit of preparsing. Specifically, I want the command to define a section with the given name, and then define a label with the name lower-cased and having spaces replaced with dashes.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\startSection{m}
{
  \section{#1}\label{\lowercase{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{-}}}
}
```

Which uses the `xstring` and `xparse` packages, but this yields an error:

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
```

After a bit of playing around I would get:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted
```

around the `\lowercase` command.

I seem to be missing some essential knowledge about how labels work, so does anyone have a good suggestion?

Comment: create a _complete_ example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\startSection}[1]{%
  \lowercase{\def\templabel{#1}}%
  \StrSubstitute{\templabel}{ }{-}[\templabel]
  \section{#1}\label{\templabel}}
```

The `\StrSubstitute` and `\lowercase` commands are not expandable, so your `\label` doesn't find anything good for it. You have to `\lowercase` first, then to `\StrSubstitute` and finally feed the string to `\label`.

However, it's just an exercise: this command will probably break if accented letters or commands are in the section title.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and yes, that did strike me, also because it's not uncommon for my LaTeX section headings to have nested commands, etc.

Comment: Use a package such as **showkeys** during document preparation: it shows labels in the margin or next to the referenced object. At a later stage it can be disabled, for the final revision, when labels are not important any more.

Comment: Perhaps this macro could be expanded to use the syntax of `\section[short title]{long title with macros}`. You probably don't want the label names to be too long at any rate.

Comment: @doncherry I wouldn't recommend using such an automatism. It can be handy *only if* section titles *are* short.