# How to unprotect a command to expand it?

Tags: expansion, protected-macro

This is another question about protection and expansion, that I still don't understand well… (and I guess this is my problem here). I read especially [How do I "unprotect" an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48825/how-do-i-unprotect-an-argument), and many others.

I'm trying to create automatic and contextual labels for titles (See below for details if needed). If I write *eg* `\myref{My_title_here}`, the link to the label is *eg* “A.II.3.d My title here”, and points to the 4th subsection of the 3rd section of the 2nd chapter in the 1st part. `A.II.3.d` is the “title number”, and is the result of `\getrefnumber {#1}` (here `#1` is `My_title_here`), and I want to get it in `\templabel`, but:

```
    %\edef \templabel {\getrefnumber {#1}} doesn't work
```

What I want is to get the result (the expansion) of `\getrefnumber {#1}` (*eg* `A.II.3.d`) in `\templabel`. Again, the code is at the end if needed.

---

**Workaround**

`\edef` didn't work, so I *finally* tried `\protected@edef` (Are `\protected\edef` and `\protected@edef` the same?):

```
    \protected@edef \templabel {\getrefnumber {#1}}
    %\show \templabel->A.\protect \textlatin  {I}.1.
```

I *finally* found this to remove `\protect`:

```
    \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \def \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \templabel \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter {\getrefnumber {#1}}
    %\show \templabel ->A.\textlatin {I}.1.
```

I looked at the definition of `\textlatin` and noticed that it really looks like `\textbf`. It's a formatting command. To remove the `\textlatin` command, I use the following:

```
    \def \textlatin #1{#1}
```

---

**Questions**

Finally it works, but:

1. Can you explain briefly what's the problem here, with protection and expansion? Why can't I use `\getrefnumber {#1}` directly?
2. I would like to know is there is a better solution, or more general, or at least, if the solution covers all cases here: how to get directly `A.I.1` instead of `A.\protect \textlatin  {I}.1`?
3. Does this solution with `\expandafter` works in each case? Which commands may I encounter here, in `\getrefnumber {#1}`: `\textlatin`, `\textgreek` (because I use `\greek`?) and what else?
4. The way I deal with the \textlatin command is it the better one? Are there any drawbacks with this solution? (I don't understand the definition of `\textlatin`, which is like `\textbf`)
5. And if I use `-` instead of `.` (A-II-3-4)? Does the `-` will be considered as an arithmetic operation, *eg* during expansion?

Feel free give advice on code, I'm learning.

---

**The context, just in case**

I use the following numbering:

```
\def \thepart          {\Alph   {part}}
\def \thechapter       {\Roman  {chapter}}
\def \thesection       {\arabic {section}}
\def \thesubsection    {\alph   {subsection}}
\def \thesubsubsection {\greek  {\value{subsubsection}}}
\setcounter {secnumdepth} {3} % Paragraphs and subparagraphs unnumbered
```

I create “informative” numbering for the titles (Source: [(Re)define \ref for chapter that includes the part number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212952/redefine-ref-for-chapter-that-includes-the-part-number)):

```
\def \p@chapter       {\thepart.}
\def \p@section       {\thepart.\thechapter.}
\def \p@subsection    {\thepart.\thechapter.\thesection.}
\def \p@subsubsection {\thepart.\thechapter.\thesection.\thesubsection.}
```

Then I create my label command that I will patch to sectionning commands (Sources:
— [Sectioning command that automatically creates label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/sectioning-command-that-automatically-creates-label),
— [Changing the output of \ref depending on the position of the corresponding \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252994/changing-the-output-of-ref-depending-on-the-position-of-the-corresponding-labe),
— [How to change the appearance of \ref depending on where it's called relative to the \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to/209218),
— [Automatic creations of labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/automatic-creations-of-labels)).

```
\newcommand {\myref }[1]{%
    \@ifundefined {r@#1} {??} {\begingroup
    %\edef \templabel {\getrefnumber {#1}} doesn't work
```

To get `A.I.2.b` in `\templabel`, this is **the problem**

Then I will split the string with xstrings:

```
    \StrCut \templabel         {.} \part@number         \part@tail
    \StrCut \part@tail         {.} \chapter@number      \chapter@tail
    % …
    \StrCut \paragraph@tail    {.} \subparagraph@number \subparagraph@tail
```

and create the contextual link (the link, his number is *eg* “A-III-2-b The title here” but if the link is in A-III, it will be only “2-b The title here”; it's contextual):

```
    \edef \templink {\getrefbykeydefault {#1} {anchor} {}}
    \IfStrEq \thepart \part@number
        {\IfStrEq \thechapter \chapter@number
            %…
            {\textcolor{red}{X} \hyperlink \templink \part@tail}}%
        {\textcolor{red}{X} \hyperlink \templink \templabel}%
    \endgroup}}
```

---

**The MWE**

```
\documentclass[greek]{book} % THE GREEK OPTION IS THE CAUSE

\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage {babel}

\makeatletter
\def \p@chapter       {\thepart.}
\def \p@section       {\thepart.\thechapter.}
\def \p@subsection    {\thepart.\thechapter.\thesection.}
\def \p@subsubsection {\thepart.\thechapter.\thesection.\thesubsection.}

\newcommand {\myref}[1]{%
    \@ifundefined {r@#1} {??} {\begingroup
        \edef \temp {\getrefnumber {#1}}
        % \show \temp->A.\textlatin {I}.1.
        \endgroup }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\part{Hi :\\introduction}\label{Hi}
\chapter{Chapter}\label{Chapter}
See \myref{Test} below.
\section{Test}\label{Test}

\enddocument
```

Comment: This looks like pretty aggressive surgery. Are you sure existing packages won't do? E.g., `nameref`, `cleveref`, ....

Comment: Can you provide a *complete*, *minimal* example? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast reply! I don't know. I think `\getrefnumber {#1}` is a command from `nameref`, which I use. I read the documentation of `cleveref`, quickly, and others too, but didn't find anything. I prefer not to use too many packages, but if there is one… I'm still interested in the answer here.

Comment: @Werner Ok, I start writing it now. I thought the answer could be an evidence.

Comment: We've got a number of questions which cover fragile and robust commands. Bottom line is that things which are robust/protected _cannot safety be expanded_ as they do things that TeX doesn't allow by expansion.

Comment: The answer to the general question in the title, is "you can't, that's why the command was protected as it will fail in an expansion context" In some special circumstances you can define alternative commands that do work via expansion, but it depends on the exact details of what you want to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — Thanks. If I understand well, depending on the protection mechanism (because I just learned there are 2), unprotecting is impossible, even if a special context would permit a safe expansion. The command is protected forever. The only way is too redefine locally (`{\def …}`) the command to do the same job as the protected command.  And that's what I've done. There is no other way. Am I right?

Comment: @user73438 yes but in general it is not possible to define a command that does the job via expansion. consider `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{\def\zzz{aaa}[\zzz]}`  if you really just need `[aaa]` then you can define `\def\foo{[aaa]}` which is the equivalent of what you have done with textlatin, but if you actually need `\zzz` to be defined after the call to `\foo` then there is no way for it to work. Similarly your textlatin redefinition only works as you don't actually need to switch font encodings in this context.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — Ok, I read it. So there are commands which expands without error in expansion-only context (en `\edef`), and commands that rely on commands unexpandable by nature (assignments like `\def`, text typesetting like `\textbf` or `\textlatin`, …), so they will throw errors if expanded in expansion-only context, so they are protected. In some cases, _eg_ if the text is not typeset and I want only access to the plain text itself, like in this question, I cannot remove the protection but I can simulate the behavior of the original command by redefining it locally in a suitable way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — Concerning the 2 protection mechanisms, one is safest than the other and rely on ε-TeX: `\protected` (`\protected\edef`, `\protected\def`…). The other one, based on LaTeX2e, uses `\protect`, `DeclareRobustCommand`, `\protected@\edef`… Are there other command names associated with these mechanisms? — I'm still not sure if one is (always) better than the other, or if there are use cases when I should use one or the other — As a guideline to code, it's better to write expandable commands (when it's possible), or to protect them (to prevent errors, but rewrite them when needed).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: too long to answer that in a comment see the linked questions or search for protect there are several longish examples giving examples. `\newcommand` also defines `\protect`-ed commands if used with an optional argument as do several other latex constructs. (almost) all expl3/xparse declarations use the etex `\protected` mechanism

Comment: To readers — The 2 answers are interesting too:<http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer, no time for more no.

`\getrefnumber` comes from package `refcount` and is full expandable. That means, it can be used inside `\edef`. But if the reference contains breakable stuff, then `\getrefnumber` will safely extract this reference, but the reference itself will break. In your case, `\textlatin` is introduced (probably by `babel`), which breaks by the hard expansion of `\edef`.

Since `\textlatin` is a macro that follows LaTeX's protection protocol, the expansion via `\protected@edef` is safe as you have observed.

Macros can be protected in LaTeX by `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Then e-TeX came up, that offers `\protected` to the definition commands to make a macro robust and prevents expansion in expandable contexts as inside `\edef`, writing to file.

`\protected\edef\macro{definition text}` makes a protected `\macro` and expands the definition text the hard way. `\protected@edef` makes a normal (unprotected) `\macro` and expands the definition text with LaTeX's protection mechanism in force.

BTW, if you use the expandable extraction commands of package `refcount` like `\getrefnumber`, then `\refused` should be used with the same label outside the expansion context to get proper warnings for undefined references.

Comment: Thanks! The comment of @DavidCarlisle complete this answer. I will search information on the differences between the 2 protection mechanisms. What I don't understand is the role of `\refused`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Throwing a warning is a non-expandable operation in LaTeX. If `\getrefnumber` is used inside `\edef` (or `\protected@edef`), then the warning will become unexpanded garbage and nothing is printed in the screen or `.log` file. `\refused` is called outside the expandable context  (e.g., before or after the definition with `\etex`), notifies the user with a warning, if the reference is still undefined, and tells LaTeX that there is an undefined reference. Then LaTeX can print its "rerun" warning at the end of the LaTeX job.

Comment: Thanks you! For the record, there is in the first answer, an example of usage : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252994/changing-the-output-of-ref-depending-on-the-position-of-the-corresponding-labe